# How can I create a plot that combines a plot of data, and a histogram of different data?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I need to create a plot that has two y-axis, and a single x-axis. On one x/y-axis pair, I need to plot several sets data (with lines). On the other x/y-axis pair, I need to plot a histogram of a different data set. The intention is to present several curves that represent the performance of several design variations, with a histogram of x-axis data, to visualize how optimized each variant is for the operating region.

Reference this example plot [plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zs7eS.jpg).

1. There are several curves on the upper plot that represent the value of `epsilon` as a function of `V` for a set of variants `A,B,C`
2. The lower plot is a histogram that represents the amount of data points collected `H` for each `V`. This data is not directly related to the upper plot. The data on the lower plot visualizes the operating region for `V`, so that it is visually obvious what regions are more important for optimization.

I looked into the seaborn documentation for "Visualizing distributions of data" [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/distributions.html).

It appears that the seaborn histograms can only be presented for the data being plotted.

I think that I need to do some combination of a separate line plot and histogram so that the correct data is represented in each plot.

I want this to be represented in a single figure, but I am unsure of the exact method to achieve this.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need:

- to share x axis: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/shared_axis_demo.html
- to adjust gap/space/padding between subplots:
  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots_adjust.html
- to Invert one of y axis (two options):
  https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/invert_axes.html
  https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.invert_yaxis.html

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'll look into it, but it appears that you have provided sufficient references to achieve what I need. I would upvote, but StackOverflow will not let me :(